# Help me identify any of these flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

My wife picked up some [Flowers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rKPR.jpg) from the store (Costco I believe) for her students to draw.   She would like to be able to tell them what the flowers are so they can label them.

[Another angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t6vD.jpg)

[A third angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ouk4q.jpg)

Comment: One plant per question please.

Comment: David, as @Niall C. said, we need one plant per question, otherwise this is likely to get closed, which, as you probably know as an experienced SE user, means it will stop being seen over time.  I'd edit this down to the most important flower and go from there. Also, would you kindly post the pictures directly in the question, so people can easily see what you mean? The flowers are pretty, and I'm sure you're not the only one who would like to know what they are. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The orange flowers are carnations.
- The purple flower on the top    (rather stiff with many blossoms
  clustered on a thick stem) is statice.
- The large green flower is a dahlia.
- The pink with yellow centers are daisies.

I'm not sure what the dark purple daisy-like flowers with the white tips are, and I think I might also see a spray of light purple freesia in there, but it is hard to tell. They're very pretty!

Comment: I believe the white-tipped daisies are Chrysanthemums.

Comment: I think you may be right, Brenn!

Comment: Hi Michelle! It was really kind of you to write an answer, but we've asked for the question to be split up in order to keep it open. If David Oneill does that, would you be willing to split this answer too, and only identify the flowers in the individual questions? That would eliminate any confusion caused if there's a question about one flower and an answer about four. Thanks!

Comment: The teacher should go back to the store and talk with the floral manager.  They will know exactly what each plant is to include the filler material.  While kids are drawing it is VASTLY effective for them to understand what they are drawing, how it lives, where it came from, how that flower was grown in a nursery even down to overhead/expenses just growing that one flower against what the teacher ended up paying to get that flower there.  Thinking is always happening while drawing why waste the opportunity?